# Writing conditional statements without using if/else/?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, c99

I am looking to write conditional code without using `(if/else/?/while etc...)` in C language.

For example the following code:

```
if (Num>6) printf("T");
```

can be converted to (And still do the same task):

```
Num>6 && printf("T")
```

but the following:

```
bool larger;
if (Num>6) larger=true;
```

can't be replaced with:

```
bool larger;
Num>6 && larger=true;
```

Since lvalue is required as left operand of assignment

Any help? (I think `&&` operation and the use of bool would be helpful)

Comment: `bool larger = Num > 6;`

Comment: @tkausl that's different, because it doesn't leave `larger` indeterminate if `Num <= 6` (though any code that could determine this on the original code would be UB). A literal translation would be `Num>6 && (larger=true);`

Comment: @EOF has given the correct answer, it works

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If my answer helps you please click the green checkmark to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). And then please take a 1-minute [tour] to know how this site works

Answer (score 2):

Add parentheses around:

```
bool larger;
Num > 6 && (larger = true);
```

Why? Because `=` has [lower precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `&&` and `>`. That means the expression is parsed as

```
((Num > 6) && larger) = true;
```

which is an invalid assignment

[Demo on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+f(int+Num)%7B%0A++++bool+larger%3B%0A++++Num+%3E+6+%26%26+(larger+%3D+true)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.1177752043527,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.88222479564731,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.88222479564731,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)